# How to add dashboard configuration json file in Grafana image?

Tags: docker, dashboard, grafana, grafana-templating, grafana-api

I have a grafana docker image which have hawkular-datasource pre-configured using configuration files.

After after running grafana instance, I have a json given by teammate, which can be imported inside grafana and that json file creates dashboard when imported.

How do I make that dashboards appear by default in Grafana instance?

I tried copying the json file to /etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards/ folder and created a new docker image. But when I run the image, the instance doesn't contain the dashboard at the homepage or anywhere in it.

How do I add this json file in docker image. Am I following the correct way?

I tried this http://docs.grafana.org/administration/provisioning/ But it didn't help out much. Any suggestion?

Here is the json file.

```
{
    "id": null,
    "title": "Openshift Metrics",
    "tags": [],
    "style": "dark",
    "timezone": "browser",
    "editable": true,
    "hideControls": false,
    "sharedCrosshair": false,
    "rows": [
      {
        "collapse": false,
        "editable": true,
        "height": "322px",
        "panels": [
          {
            "content": "<center><p style='font-size: 40pt'>$app</p></center>",
            "editable": true,
            "error": false,
            "id": 23,
            "isNew": true,
            "links": [],
            "mode": "html",
            "repeatIteration": 1476706310439,
            "scopedVars": {},
            "span": 2,
            "style": {
              "font-size": "36pt"
            },
            "title": "",
            "type": "text"
          },
          {
            "aliasColors": {},
            "bars": false,
            "datasource": "Hawk-DS",
            "editable": true,
            "error": false,
            "fill": 1,
            "grid": {
              "threshold1": null,
              "threshold1Color": "rgba(216, 200, 27, 0.27)",
              "threshold2": null,
              "threshold2Color": "rgba(234, 112, 112, 0.22)"
            },
            "id": 9,
            "isNew": true,
            "legend": {
              "avg": false,
              "current": false,
              "max": false,
              "min": false,
              "show": true,
              "total": false,
              "values": false
            },
            "lines": true,
            "linewidth": 2,
            "links": [],
            "nullPointMode": "connected",
            "percentage": false,
            "pointradius": 5,
            "points": false,
            "renderer": "flot",
            "repeatIteration": 1476706310439,
            "scopedVars": {},
            "seriesOverrides": [],
            "span": 6,
            "stack": false,
            "steppedLine": false,
            "targets": [
              {
                "queryBy": "tags",
                "rate": false,
                "refId": "A",
                "seriesAggFn": "none",
                "tags": [
                  {
                    "name": "container_name",
                    "value": "$app"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "descriptor_name",
                    "value": "memory/usage"
                  }
                ],
                "target": "select metric",
                "tagsQL": "container_name IN [$app] AND descriptor_name='memory/usage'",
                "timeAggFn": "avg",
                "type": "gauge"
              }
            ],
            "timeFrom": null,
            "timeShift": null,
            "title": "Memory usage",
            "tooltip": {
              "msResolution": true,
              "shared": true,
              "sort": 0,
              "value_type": "cumulative"
            },
            "type": "graph",
            "xaxis": {
              "show": true
            },
            "yaxes": [
              {
                "format": "bytes",
                "label": null,
                "logBase": 1,
                "max": null,
                "min": 0,
                "show": true
              },
              {
                "format": "short",
                "label": null,
                "logBase": 1,
                "max": null,
                "min": null,
                "show": true
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "cacheTimeout": null,
            "colorBackground": true,
            "colorValue": false,
            "colors": [
              "rgba(50, 172, 45, 0.97)",
              "rgba(237, 129, 40, 0.89)",
              "rgba(245, 54, 54, 0.9)"
            ],
            "datasource": "Hawk-DS",
            "editable": true,
            "error": false,
            "format": "bytes",
            "gauge": {
              "maxValue": 100,
              "minValue": 0,
              "show": false,
              "thresholdLabels": false,
              "thresholdMarkers": true
            },
            "height": "100px",
            "id": 12,
            "interval": null,
            "isNew": true,
            "links": [],
            "mappingType": 1,
            "mappingTypes": [
              {
                "name": "value to text",
                "value": 1
              },
              {
                "name": "range to text",
                "value": 2
              }
            ],
            "maxDataPoints": 100,
            "nullPointMode": "connected",
            "nullText": null,
            "postfix": "",
            "postfixFontSize": "50%",
            "prefix": "",
            "prefixFontSize": "50%",
            "rangeMaps": [
              {
                "from": "null",
                "text": "N/A",
                "to": "null"
              }
            ],
            "repeatIteration": 1476706310439,
            "scopedVars": {},
            "span": 2,
            "sparkline": {
              "fillColor": "rgba(31, 118, 189, 0.18)",
              "full": false,
              "lineColor": "rgb(31, 120, 193)",
              "show": false
            },
            "targets": [
              {
                "queryBy": "tags",
                "rate": false,
                "refId": "A",
                "seriesAggFn": "sum",
                "tags": [
                  {
                    "name": "container_name",
                    "value": "$app"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "descriptor_name",
                    "value": "memory/usage"
                  }
                ],
                "target": "select metric",
                "tagsQL": "container_name IN [$app] AND descriptor_name='memory/usage'",
                "timeAggFn": "live",
                "type": "gauge"
              }
            ],
            "thresholds": "140000000,180000000",
            "title": "Live, all pods",
            "type": "singlestat",
            "valueFontSize": "80%",
            "valueMaps": [
              {
                "op": "=",
                "text": "N/A",
                "value": "null"
              }
            ],
            "valueName": "avg"
          },
          {
            "cacheTimeout": null,
            "colorBackground": true,
            "colorValue": false,
            "colors": [
              "rgba(50, 172, 45, 0.97)",
              "rgba(237, 129, 40, 0.89)",
              "rgba(245, 54, 54, 0.9)"
            ],
            "datasource": "Hawk-DS",
            "editable": true,
            "error": false,
            "format": "bytes",
            "gauge": {
              "maxValue": 100,
              "minValue": 0,
              "show": false,
              "thresholdLabels": false,
              "thresholdMarkers": true
            },
            "height": "100px",
            "id": 15,
            "interval": null,
            "isNew": true,
            "links": [],
            "mappingType": 1,
            "mappingTypes": [
              {
                "name": "value to text",
                "value": 1
              },
              {
                "name": "range to text",
                "value": 2
              }
            ],
            "maxDataPoints": 100,
            "nullPointMode": "connected",
            "nullText": null,
            "postfix": "",
            "postfixFontSize": "50%",
            "prefix": "",
            "prefixFontSize": "50%",
            "rangeMaps": [
              {
                "from": "null",
                "text": "N/A",
                "to": "null"
              }
            ],
            "repeatIteration": 1476706310439,
            "scopedVars": {},
            "span": 2,
            "sparkline": {
              "fillColor": "rgba(31, 118, 189, 0.18)",
              "full": false,
              "lineColor": "rgb(31, 120, 193)",
              "show": false
            },
            "targets": [
              {
                "queryBy": "tags",
                "rate": false,
                "refId": "A",
                "seriesAggFn": "avg",
                "tags": [
                  {
                    "name": "container_name",
                    "value": "$app"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "descriptor_name",
                    "value": "memory/usage"
                  }
                ],
                "target": "select metric",
                "tagsQL": "container_name IN [$app] AND descriptor_name='memory/usage'",
                "timeAggFn": "live",
                "type": "gauge"
              }
            ],
            "thresholds": "140000000,180000000",
            "title": "Live per pod",
            "type": "singlestat",
            "valueFontSize": "80%",
            "valueMaps": [
              {
                "op": "=",
                "text": "N/A",
                "value": "null"
              }
            ],
            "valueName": "avg"
          },
          {
            "cacheTimeout": null,
            "colorBackground": true,
            "colorValue": false,
            "colors": [
              "rgba(50, 172, 45, 0.97)",
              "rgba(237, 129, 40, 0.89)",
              "rgba(245, 54, 54, 0.9)"
            ],
            "datasource": "Hawk-DS",
            "editable": true,
            "error": false,
            "format": "bytes",
            "gauge": {
              "maxValue": 100,
              "minValue": 0,
              "show": false,
              "thresholdLabels": false,
              "thresholdMarkers": true
            },
            "height": "100px",
            "id": 10,
            "interval": null,
            "isNew": true,
            "links": [],
            "mappingType": 1,
            "mappingTypes": [
              {
                "name": "value to text",
                "value": 1
              },
              {
                "name": "range to text",
                "value": 2
              }
            ],
            "maxDataPoints": 100,
            "nullPointMode": "connected",
            "nullText": null,
            "postfix": "",
            "postfixFontSize": "50%",
            "prefix": "",
            "prefixFontSize": "50%",
            "rangeMaps": [
              {
                "from": "null",
                "text": "N/A",
                "to": "null"
              }
            ],
            "repeatIteration": 1476706310439,
            "scopedVars": {},
            "span": 2,
            "sparkline": {
              "fillColor": "rgba(31, 118, 189, 0.18)",
              "full": false,
              "lineColor": "rgb(31, 120, 193)",
              "show": false
            },
            "targets": [
              {
                "queryBy": "tags",
                "rate": false,
                "refId": "A",
                "seriesAggFn": "sum",
                "tags": [
                  {
                    "name": "container_name",
                    "value": "$app"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "descriptor_name",
                    "value": "memory/usage"
                  }
                ],
                "target": "select metric",
                "tagsQL": "container_name IN [$app] AND descriptor_name='memory/usage'",
                "timeAggFn": "avg",
                "type": "gauge"
              }
            ],
            "thresholds": "140000000,180000000",
            "title": "Average, all pods",
            "type": "singlestat",
            "valueFontSize": "80%",
            "valueMaps": [
              {
                "op": "=",
                "text": "N/A",
                "value": "null"
              }
            ],
            "valueName": "avg"
          },
          {
            "cacheTimeout": null,
            "colorBackground": true,
            "colorValue": false,
            "colors": [
              "rgba(50, 172, 45, 0.97)",
              "rgba(237, 129, 40, 0.89)",
              "rgba(245, 54, 54, 0.9)"
            ],
            "datasource": "Hawk-DS",
            "editable": true,
            "error": false,
            "format": "bytes",
            "gauge": {
              "maxValue": 100,
              "minValue": 0,
              "show": false,
              "thresholdLabels": false,
              "thresholdMarkers": true
            },
            "height": "100px",
            "id": 13,
            "interval": null,
            "isNew": true,
            "links": [],
            "mappingType": 1,
            "mappingTypes": [
              {
                "name": "value to text",
                "value": 1
              },
              {
                "name": "range to text",
                "value": 2
              }
            ],
            "maxDataPoints": 100,
            "nullPointMode": "connected",
            "nullText": null,
            "postfix": "",
            "postfixFontSize": "50%",
            "prefix": "",
            "prefixFontSize": "50%",
            "rangeMaps": [
              {
                "from": "null",
                "text": "N/A",
                "to": "null"
              }
            ],
            "repeatIteration": 1476706310439,
            "scopedVars": {},
            "span": 2,
            "sparkline": {
              "fillColor": "rgba(31, 118, 189, 0.18)",
              "full": false,
              "lineColor": "rgb(31, 120, 193)",
              "show": false
            },
            "targets": [
              {
                "queryBy": "tags",
                "rate": false,
                "refId": "A",
                "seriesAggFn": "avg",
                "tags": [
                  {
                    "name": "container_name",
                    "value": "$app"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "descriptor_name",
                    "value": "memory/usage"
                  }
                ],
                "target": "select metric",
                "tagsQL": "container_name IN [$app] AND descriptor_name='memory/usage'",
                "timeAggFn": "avg",
                "type": "gauge"
              }
            ],
            "thresholds": "140000000,180000000",
            "title": "Average per pod",
            "type": "singlestat",
            "valueFontSize": "80%",
            "valueMaps": [
              {
                "op": "=",
                "text": "N/A",
                "value": "null"
              }
            ],
            "valueName": "avg"
          },
          {
            "cacheTimeout": null,
            "colorBackground": true,
            "colorValue": false,
            "colors": [
              "rgba(50, 172, 45, 0.97)",
              "rgba(237, 129, 40, 0.89)",
              "rgba(245, 54, 54, 0.9)"
            ],
            "datasource": "Hawk-DS",
            "editable": true,
            "error": false,
            "format": "bytes",
            "gauge": {
              "maxValue": 100,
              "minValue": 0,
              "show": false,
              "thresholdLabels": false,
              "thresholdMarkers": true
            },
            "height": "100px",
            "id": 11,
            "interval": null,
            "isNew": true,
            "links": [],
            "mappingType": 1,
            "mappingTypes": [
              {
                "name": "value to text",
                "value": 1
              },
              {
                "name": "range to text",
                "value": 2
              }
            ],
            "maxDataPoints": 100,
            "nullPointMode": "connected",
            "nullText": null,
            "postfix": "",
            "postfixFontSize": "50%",
            "prefix": "",
            "prefixFontSize": "50%",
            "rangeMaps": [
              {
                "from": "null",
                "text": "N/A",
                "to": "null"
              }
            ],
            "repeatIteration": 1476706310439,
            "scopedVars": {},
            "span": 2,
            "sparkline": {
              "fillColor": "rgba(31, 118, 189, 0.18)",
              "full": false,
              "lineColor": "rgb(31, 120, 193)",
              "show": false
            },
            "targets": [
              {
                "queryBy": "tags",
                "rate": false,
                "refId": "A",
                "seriesAggFn": "sum",
                "tags": [
                  {
                    "name": "container_name",
                    "value": "$app"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "descriptor_name",
                    "value": "memory/usage"
                  }
                ],
                "target": "select metric",
                "tagsQL": "container_name IN [$app] AND descriptor_name='memory/usage'",
                "timeAggFn": "max",
                "type": "gauge"
              }
            ],
            "thresholds": "140000000,180000000",
            "title": "Max, all pods",
            "type": "singlestat",
            "valueFontSize": "80%",
            "valueMaps": [
              {
                "op": "=",
                "text": "N/A",
                "value": "null"
              }
            ],
            "valueName": "avg"
          },
          {
            "cacheTimeout": null,
            "colorBackground": true,
            "colorValue": false,
            "colors": [
              "rgba(50, 172, 45, 0.97)",
              "rgba(237, 129, 40, 0.89)",
              "rgba(245, 54, 54, 0.9)"
            ],
            "datasource": "Hawk-DS",
            "editable": true,
            "error": false,
            "format": "bytes",
            "gauge": {
              "maxValue": 100,
              "minValue": 0,
              "show": false,
              "thresholdLabels": false,
              "thresholdMarkers": true
            },
            "height": "100px",
            "id": 14,
            "interval": null,
            "isNew": true,
            "links": [],
            "mappingType": 1,
            "mappingTypes": [
              {
                "name": "value to text",
                "value": 1
              },
              {
                "name": "range to text",
                "value": 2
              }
            ],
            "maxDataPoints": 100,
            "nullPointMode": "connected",
            "nullText": null,
            "postfix": "",
            "postfixFontSize": "50%",
            "prefix": "",
            "prefixFontSize": "50%",
            "rangeMaps": [
              {
                "from": "null",
                "text": "N/A",
                "to": "null"
              }
            ],
            "repeatIteration": 1476706310439,
            "scopedVars": {},
            "span": 2,
            "sparkline": {
              "fillColor": "rgba(31, 118, 189, 0.18)",
              "full": false,
              "lineColor": "rgb(31, 120, 193)",
              "show": false
            },
            "targets": [
              {
                "queryBy": "tags",
                "rate": false,
                "refId": "A",
                "seriesAggFn": "avg",
                "tags": [
                  {
                    "name": "container_name",
                    "value": "$app"
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "descriptor_name",
                    "value": "memory/usage"
                  }
                ],
                "target": "select metric",
                "tagsQL": "container_name IN [$app] AND descriptor_name='memory/usage'",
                "timeAggFn": "max",
                "type": "gauge"
              }
            ],
            "thresholds": "140000000,180000000",
            "title": "Max per pod",
            "type": "singlestat",
            "valueFontSize": "80%",
            "valueMaps": [
              {
                "op": "=",
                "text": "N/A",
                "value": "null"
              }
            ],
            "valueName": "avg"
          }
        ],
        "repeat": "app",
        "scopedVars": {
          "app": {
            "text": "aloha",
            "value": "aloha",
            "selected": true
          }
        },
        "title": "New row"
      }
    ],
    "time": {
      "from": "now-30m",
      "to": "now"
    },
    "timepicker": {
      "refresh_intervals": [
        "5s",
        "10s",
        "30s",
        "1m",
        "5m",
        "15m",
        "30m",
        "1h",
        "2h",
        "1d"
      ],
      "time_options": [
        "5m",
        "15m",
        "1h",
        "6h",
        "12h",
        "24h",
        "2d",
        "7d",
        "30d"
      ]
    },
    "templating": {
      "list": [
        {
          "current": {},
          "datasource": "Hawk-DS",
          "hide": 0,
          "includeAll": true,
          "label": "Application",
          "multi": true,
          "name": "app",
          "options": [],
          "query": "tags/container_name:*",
          "refresh": 1,
          "regex": "",
          "type": "query"
        }
      ]
    },
    "annotations": {
      "list": []
    },
    "schemaVersion": 12,
    "version": 32,
    "links": [],
    "gnetId": null
}
```

Comment: Welcome. Please provide any relevant files (json, Dockerfile, docker-compose.yml, etc.) so that we can help you debug your scenario.

Comment: added the json file. I'm not sure if there should be a specific naming convention to follow for dashboards. Please clarify.

Comment: What command line did you use to start your grafana container?

Comment: We are deploying the container on Openshift container platform. Not giving any commands to run manually. I guess it takes care of it internally.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should put a YAML file pointing to the JSON files in that folder. For example write `/etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards/local.yml`:

```
apiVersion: 1

providers:
- name: 'default'
  orgId: 1
  folder: ''
  type: file
  disableDeletion: false
  updateIntervalSeconds: 10 #how often Grafana will scan for changed dashboards
  options:
    path: /var/lib/grafana/dashboards
```

And then write your JSON file to `/var/lib/grafana/dashboards/openshift.json`.

---

Before Grafana 5, my previous solution was to wrap the whole Docker process in a script that uses the [API](http://docs.grafana.org/http_api/dashboard/) to create the dashboard once the Docker container is up. You can use the `GF_SECURITY_ADMIN_PASSWORD` environment variable to set the password. You can also use `GF_AUTH_ANONYMOUS_ENABLED`, but you'll need to make sure it's not accessible to the outside world.

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 -e GF_AUTH_ANONYMOUS_ENABLED=true grafana/grafana ...
sleep 10  # wait for grafana to load (use a better method of waiting in production)
curl -skfS -XPOST --header "Content-Type: application/json" "http://localhost:3000/grafana/api/dashboards/db" --data-binary @dashboard.json
```

Comment: But is there any way to include them as part of Docker image itself that will be loaded on homepage? just like we are adding datasources file in provisioning folder inside docker image?

Answer (score 13):

I've faced with the same problem and I hope the next solution could help somebody.
For example, you have the next working directory:

```
├── docker-compose.yml          
├── grafana                     
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── dashboards
│   │   └── exported_dashboard.json    #dashboard you saved before
│   └── provisioning            
│       │                       
│       ├── dashboards          
│       │   └── all.yml         
│       └── datasources
│           └── all.yml
```

1. In the `Dockerfile` you have to add `provisioning` and `dashboards` folders into grafana container:

```
FROM grafana/grafana:latest
ADD ./provisioning /etc/grafana/provisioning
ADD ./dashboards /var/lib/grafana/dashboards
```

2. In `provisioning/dashboards/all.yml` you have to set path to imported dashboards folder
   where `exported_dashboard.json` is actually placed:

```yaml
- name: 'default'
  org_id: 1
  folder: ''
  type: 'file'
  options:
    folder: '/var/lib/grafana/dashboards'
```

3. **[Optional]** Then you also can configure default datasourse in `provisioning/datasources/all.yml`, prometheus, for example:

```yaml
datasources:
-  access: 'proxy'
   editable: true
   is_default: true
   name: 'prom1'
   org_id: 1
   type: 'prometheus'
   url: 'http://prometheus:9090'
   version: 1
```

4. Finally, `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  grafana:
    image: awesome-grafana:latest
    build:
      context: grafana
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    environment:
      GF_DASHBOARDS_DEFAULT_HOME_DASHBOARD_PATH: "/var/lib/grafana/dashboards/exported_dashboard.json"
```

- As for **HOME** dashborad, you can use the `GF_DASHBOARDS_DEFAULT_HOME_DASHBOARD_PATH` evironment variable, as shown above.
  More about `GF_DASHBOARDS_DEFAULT_HOME_DASHBOARD_PATH` evironment variable you can read in that [github issue](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/26441).
- The full comprehensive code example you can find in the next [github repository](https://github.com/cirocosta/sample-grafana)
- Original article with explanation [there](https://ops.tips/blog/initialize-grafana-with-preconfigured-dashboards/).